# Get all values of some parameter for all documents in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to get 'xxx' parameter of all documents in Marklogic using query like:

```
(/doc/document)/xxx
```

But since we have very big documents database I get an error "Expanded tree cache full on host". I don't have admin rights for this server, so I can't change configuration. I suggest that I can use ranges while getting documents like:

```
(/doc/document)[1 to 1000]/xxx
```

and then

```
(/doc/document)[1000 to 2000]/xxx
```

etc, but I'm concerned that I do not know how it works, for example, what will happen if during this process database will be changed (f.e. a new document will be added), how will it affect the result documents list? Also I don't know which order it uses in case when I use ranges...

Please clarify, is this way can be appropriate or is there any other ways to get some parameter of all documents?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how big your database is there may be no way to get all the values in one transaction.
Suppose you have a trillion documents, the result set will be bigger then can be returned in one transaction.
Is that important ? Only your business case can tell.
The most efficient way of getting all "xxx" values is with a range index.  You can see how this works
with cts:element-values  ( https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values )

You do need to be able to create a range index over the element "xxxx" to do this (ask your DBA).

Then cts:element-values() returns *only* those values and the chances of being able to return most or all of them
in memory in a signle transaction is much higher then using xpath (/doc/document/xxx) which as you wrote actualy returns all the "xxx" elements (not just their values).  The most likely requires actually loading every document matching /doc and then parsing it and returning the xxx element.  That can be both slow and inefficient.
A range index just stores the values and you can retrieve those without ever having to load the actual document.
In general when working with large datasets learning how to access data in MarkLogic using *only* indexes will produce the fastest results.

Comment: Thank you very much, but is it possible to get all existing indexes in the MarkLogic database? Maybe this index over the element "xxxx" already exists..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add - I meant the situation when I don't have admin rights for the ML DB